# I would like to take a div and curve it like a next thermostat temperature range and implementing a slider within that div

Tags: javascript, css, css-shapes, rangeslider

[Nest Thermostat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjjLy.png)

I'm drawing up ways to curve the div to make it to that shape like in the picture above, but I'm a bit lost on how to do so. Also implementing a range slider for the temperatures inside that curved div and on mouseover/hover the slider would increase the numerical temperature shown on the screen span. The range slider would then animate to have the current `div.temp` to be bolder until the last `div.temp` after the mouse out. I'm stuck with this part and just need a bit of guidance.
My original code I was working with  looked like this:

```
      <div class="temp-range">
      <div class="temp" value="40">|</div>
      <div class="temp" value="41">|</div>
      <div class="temp" value="42">|</div>
      <div class="temp" value="43">|</div>
      <div class="temp" value="44">|</div>
      <div class="temp" value="45">|</div>

      <span class="Val"></span>
      </div>
```

Comment: Found this guy: https://www.svidget.io/examples/nestthermostat

Comment: Thank you so much This going to be a bit more complex than I thought but Im ready. Thank you.